# Selecting first non null value in a model

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a model class that looks like this:

```
   public class ModelTest {
        public string val1 {get;set;}
        public string val2 {get;set;}
        public string val3 {get;set;}
   }
```

Somewhere in my code this ModelTest gets its data. The caveat is that, only 1 of them will hold a value

```
   var model = new ModelTest() {val1=null, val2="value", val3=null} //Sudo code
```

What I am trying to do somehow, is compare a value to whichever 1 of the 3 items can potentially have a values, so something like:

```
     var testCompare = "someValue"

     if (testCompare == model. ....//how can I get the NOT NULL value from ModelTest here for comparison
```

Comment: If only one of them has a value, then why not have `public string val;` and `public int which;`?  No confusion then.  Make it impossible to have inconsistent state.

Comment: Check the coalescing operator, ??= and ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your data model isn't ideal, it is possible to check each of the properties by utilizing the `||` operator to compare each value. As long as your `testCompare` variable does not contain null, you can also omit a null check.

```
if (model.val1 == testCompare || 
    model.val2 == testCompare || 
    model.val3 == testCompare)
{ }
```

As mentioned in the comments, if you want a more succinct version, you can use the null coalescing operator, `??`, to check subsequent properties if your prior property returns null. At the end of the null coalescing chain, the first non-null property will be compared to your `testCompare` string. Note that you must wrap all three properties in parentheses and that this has different behavior; it only tests the first non-null property whereas the previous version tests ALL properties for a match.

```
if (testCompare == (model.val1 ?? model.val2 ?? model.val3))
{
}
```

Comment: I thought maybe there's a LINQ shortcut to do this. Thanks

Comment: Or maybe like Luc suggested, `testCompare == model.val1 ?? model.val2 ?? model.val3`.

Comment: @Shrimp2022, why LINQ? You don't even have a list.

Comment: @Shrimp2022 you certainly can use LINQ, but to Andrew's point, it is designed to be used against collection types. If you create a collection solely to use LINQ, you hurt the performance of your code.

Comment: @Andrew I added a null coalescing version, with caveats that the behavior is not identical.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably create a method (or even property) like:

```cs
public string Val()
{
    if (val1 != null) return val1;
    if (val2 != null) return val2;
    if (val3 != null) return val3;
    return null;
}
```

There is probably a shorter way to write this code. Also, if two or more of the values are not null, then it will return the first one.

Comment: The shorter way would be `return val1 ?? val2 ?? val3;`. BTW, your final `return` is missing the `;`.

Comment: That shorter way seems nice. Also I added the `;`, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could add a property to your `ModelTest` class that provides the first non-null value (if any) in your object:

```
public class ModelTest
{
    public string val1 { get; set; }
    public string val2 { get; set; }
    public string val3 { get; set; }

    public string val => val1 ?? val2 ?? val3;
}
```

and then check against that:

```
if (model.val == testCompare) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

What about solution which contains combination of reflection and Linq,

**Test Data**

```
var model = new ModelTest() {val1=null, val2="value", val3=null} ;
```

**Usage**

```
var result = 
    model.GetType()
    .GetProperties()
    .FirstOrDefault(prop => prop.GetValue(model, null) != null);
```

**Print result**

```
Console.WriteLine(result.GetValue(model));
```

<sup>This is my first attempt with reflection, suggestions are most welcome</sup>

[.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/W18L8k)

---

**Note:** This is just an **alternate** solution, less **performant**. If you are looking for elegant solution, then kindly try other solutions.

Comment: Some "warning, if you need this to be performant, don't do this" banner would be nice! 

Comment: Done, added note

Answer (score 1):

It's a very bizarre use case, but let's go with it. Here's another option for the bonfire..

```
public class ModelTest {
    private string _val;
    public string val1 {get => _val; set => _val ??= value;}
    public string val2 {get => _val; set => _val ??= value;}
    public string val3 {get => _val; set => _val ??= value;}
}
```

Whichever one of these is set to non null ends up committing that value to `_val` - `??=` writes the right hand into the left hand only if the left hand is null, essentially like `left = left ?? right`.

It doesn't matter which you use to access the value..

Note that there is only one data storage location so this approach is incapable of remembering two values, or which value was the non null. You wouldn't use this for disparate properties like name, address and social security number because it could lead to bizarre effects elsewhere. This is for a very narrow use case of "there are three properties that are essentially the same thing, they cannot be collapsed to one, and I don't know which one will be set but i can treat them equivalent for reading"

Answer (score 1):

You can override the method 'Equals' of ModelTest class however you like. Example:

```
public class ModelTest {

    public string val1 {get;set;}
    public string val2 {get;set;}
    public string val3 {get;set;}

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if(!typeof(string).IsInstanceOfType(obj))
            return base.Equals(obj);

        string value = obj as string;

        if (val1.Equals(value))
            return true;

        if (val2.Equals(value))
            return true;

        if (val3.Equals(value))
            return true;

        return false;
    }

}
```

For to use the method:

```
if(model.Equals("yourValue"))
...
```

Comment: I think having a class with 3 properties say that it *equals* a string can be confusing.

Comment: @Andrew how about overriding so that is compared with an another instance of ModelTest, where any prop equal any other prop (9 comparisons)?

Comment: In the land of possibilities, we can come up with hundreds of options. The questions are what is necessary and what makes sense. That possibility you mention looks also very confusing. If that logic was useful, I would call it differently and not `Equals`.